# Using Trace within Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, trace, global-asax

I'm struggling to output the messages written via Trace.WriteLine within the Global.asax, they don't appear in the Trace.axd.

I've added a `WebPageTraceListener` and a `TextWriterTraceListener` as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) but all I see are the normal page events you would see in a trace which is expected.

Am I missing a step in order to get trace messages written in the Global.asax to the file/trace log? I'm doing some logging in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you compile using the `TRACE` switch or update your web.config to do so automatically?

From the MSDN page you linked to (emphasis mine):

> Although ASP.NET displays trace messages whenever tracing is enabled
>   for a page, System.Diagnostics trace messages are written **only when
>   the code in which the trace messages reside is compiled by using an
>   explicit compiler switch—the TRACE switch**. In other words, if you do
>   not explicitly compile the AuthorClass using the TRACE switch, you
>   will not see the trace messages, even with the `WebPageTraceListener`
>   added.
>
> You can configure your application to automatically compile using the
>   TRACE switch, by adding a new section to your Web.config file.

This is the Web.config entry that should be placed after the `<system.diagnostics>` section:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
              extension=".cs" 
              compilerOptions="/d:TRACE"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" />
    <compiler language="VB"
              extension=".vb" 
              compilerOptions="/d:Trace=true"
              type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: I made the changes mentioned above to my web.config file. However trace.axd still does not show the trace information that I added in my global.asax.cs=> Application_Start event.